# How to apply css to a specific component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

How to apply css to a specific component?

For ex: in App.js, I included Login, Register components for routes.

In Login.css I added some css and imported in Login.js.

Now css that are imported in Login component are also applied in Register component as well.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please show you Register and login component code if possible

Comment: You can check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-loginlogout

Answer (score 2):

You are doing great, as you told you you have imported both `Login` and `Register` components in `App` root `React` functional component.

This was the problem when I stuck before  two months ago when I started using CSS in React components.

Use of `CSS Modules` differs from one version to different versions of `React`.

If you bootstrapped your project with `creat-react-app` `version >= V2`, you just have to use [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/), and it will work like charm.
Please follow, instructions and installation.

Answer (score 1):

in your webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I didn't used webpack. Any other suggestion without using webpack ?

Comment: Did you create the project by create-react-app? If yes you can run 'npm run eject' and webpack config will be in config folder

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to apply styles to your component.

1. you can have multiple css files like login.css and that has specific classes of  that file.
2. class names in `index.css` and use that classes in the required places, it will be very helpefull if you have lot of components and you wish to make your app looks with the same styling across all pages.
3. If you are not resusing styles, there is no point of creating a `css` file and importing it. Just declare a `styleConst` which is an object of styles and you can directly use it like `<div style={styleConst} />`